# Network setup help

Tags: networking, ubuntu, linux, linux-networking

I'm going to set up a network that looks like this:

- There is no Internet connection, i.e. this is a closed network.
- There will be one Ubuntu 10.04 server (64-bit) that handles all the services required (DHCP, DNS, NFS...).
- There will be two subnets. The devices on each subnet will be connected through a switch to the server. These subnets will have different address spaces (10.0.0.x and 192.0.0.x).
- It will still be possible to directly connect from a device in the other subnet to the other without any restrictions.

I have never done this before so I have been reading some documents but there are several things I'm unsure of and I'm not quite sure I've have designed this correctly.

First of all, I guess I have to create a bridge between the two networks in the server?

Secondly, is this the right way to do it? Should I connect the two switches together because I wonder what sort of performance hit I'm looking at if all of the traffic goes through the server's network interfaces? There will be maybe a few dozen devices per network but the server will also work as a simple NFS server (but I don't expect the network traffic of this service to be very high) and do a few other tasks (HDD and processor intensive).

What else should I consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood by your description, you want do somethink like this:

```
  (subnet "10.0.0.x")               (subnet "192.0.0.x")

[PC 1] [PC 2] ... [PC n]          [PC 1] [PC 2] ... [PC n]
   |     |          |                |     |          |
[ ----- switch 1 ----- ]          [ ----- switch 2 ----- ]
           ||                               ||
            ===============  ================
                         ||  ||
                     {eth0} {eth1}
                 ---------------------
                [ Ubuntu 10.04 server ]
                [                     ]
                [(DHCP), (DNS), (NFS) ]
                 ---------------------
```

So below I'll try answer your Q:

- **> "I guess I have to create a bridge between the two networks in the server?"**

No, not necessarily.

To start with, ensure IP forwarding enabled at your Ubuntu box: check `/etc/network/options`, find there `ip_forward` value, it should be `ip_forward=yes`. If the value was "no", set it to yes and restart the network service.

Second, you should configure route table by right way. In our case you should add next routes:

```
route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
route add -net 192.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth1
```

- **> "...is this the right way to do it?", "...I don't expect the network traffic of this service to be very high"**

In this case network constructed as listed above should be enough.

Comment: OK, thanks! That pretty covers my questions and yes, that's the topology that I have planned. I guess if the traffic gets high, I could always add a dedicated router to the network?

Comment: hmm... I think in this case be better use 1000Mbit ethernet connection.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a bridge perse.

- You could hardcode a routing table in all the devices connected, that tells the workstation on what interfaces the subnets can be found.
- If you use the server as the defaultroute in your network and connect both nets physically to the server (two network interfaces) it can act as a router between the subnets. In that case you only need to alter the routing table on your server.

Comment: And enable IP routing (IIRC it tends to be disabled by default). The relevant file in /proc is /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward and 0 indicates "no routing", whereas 1 indicates routing.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% on unix, but you need some form of routing between the 2 address ranges, Windows gives you routing and remote access not sure if Ubuntu has a similar application. You may need to consider a layer 3 switch.
I'm afriad that's all I can offer to you!

Comment: Unix-based routing usually occurs deep in the OS itself, rather than at the application level.  RRaS is indeed something windows-specific.